# Modifying user-input file path to scan files in the same directory in C

Tags: c, string, file, filepath, data-manipulation

I'm working on a program where the user inputs the file path, then an additional string with the file name is concatenated to that. I will be using this for multiple files in the same directory.
I am using printf statement is just to see if the operation works, however when the output is displayed **the filepath is printed twice**, then the filename added at the end. For example

Input filepath is `C:\Documents\`

the output comes out `C:\Documents\C:\Documents\HR_1.txt`

How can this be corrected?

The relevant code is below

```
int main()
{
            char folder[50]="";
            printf("Please type file location\n");
            printf("An example of file location is C:\\Documents\\projects\\[Folder]\\");
            printf("\n");
            scanf("%s",folder);
            printf(folder);

            /*Clearing Heart rate file names, opening file*/
            FILE*HR1=NULL;
            printf(strcat(folder,"HR_1.txt"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post complete code that reproduces the above output along with your input.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, but even more importantly,
please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).
You need to show declarations, and a complete (but minimal) program that illustrates the problem you face.

Comment: I've added my full code. Also, whenever I print only `folder` the output is exactly as typed by the user

Comment: Note that a minimal example would not bother with the menu printing, or getting the option when you're interested in the option 1 code.  Please go back and reread the MCVE guidelines.  Note: 'minimal' means "nothing can be removed without stopping the reproduction of the problem".

Comment: Note that you've still not shown how you defined the variable `folder`.  There are lots of ways of doing it wrong.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for being so patient. I now added the definition of `folder` and removed everything that is unrelated to this question (I belive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the output of two calls to `printf` mashed together.

The first parameter to `printf` should **always** be a string literal, not a variable.  That prevents unintended escape sequences from being interpreted and allows you to put newlines in your formatting.

Because your two calls to `printf`, one before appending and one after, don't include a newline, they appear on the same line.

So change this:

```
        printf(folder);
        ...
        printf(strcat(folder,"HR_1.txt"));
```

To:

```
        printf("%s\n", folder);
        ...
        printf("%s\n", strcat(folder,"HR_1.txt"));
```

Output:

```
C:\Documents\
C:\Documents\HR_1.txt
```

Comment: And it might be better to add markers to help spot unwanted characters, like `printf("Before: [[%s]]\n", folder);` and similarly for `After`.  The OP will need to keep a record of where the end of the original input was if the folder is going to be used multiple times, but that's beyond the immediate problem.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, this solved the issue as far as printing the correct path with the filename.